# Show top N items from dropdown-menu with jQuery Slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, slice

I am trying to show only the top 10 results of each list in my navigation. I have about 5 UL's and want to show the top 10 results of each. code below works only the first list. What am I missing here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elements = $(".dropdown .dropdown-menu li");
  var index = 0;

  var showFirstTen = function(index) {
    if (index >= elements.length) {
      index = 0;
    }
    console.log(index);
    elements.hide().slice(index, index + 10).show();
  }

  showFirstTen(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/">Music Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Desk Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Home Automation</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Camera Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Monitors Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Phone Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Storage Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Communications Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your markup as well?

Comment: @ NuclearGhost updated with markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css` for that:

```
li:nth-child(n+11) {
    display: none;
}
```

This will make sure only the first 10 `li` elements will be displayed.

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+11) {
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example (with background-change instead of hiding), just to see how it works (every `li` that it's pos>5 will get green background).

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+6) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 3</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 4</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 5</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 6</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 7</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 8</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/accessories.aspx" target="" data-toggle="">Accessories 9</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Music Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Devices &amp; Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Desk Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home Automation</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Camera Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Mobility Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" >Monitors Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Tablet Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Phone Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Scanner Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Projector Accessorie</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Storage Accessories</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Communications Accessories</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are welcome :) will appreciate a voteup when you have enough reputation for that (min of 15).

Answer (score 1):

Dekel's solution w.r.t CSS looks great.

But, when I ran the code snippet, the items has green background correctly till "Accessories 5".
Then, remaining ul's were all green.
Didn't check it further.

Instead, I implemented a similar solution in JQUERY.

Please find the jsfiddle url below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj85/yu2eLgLh/1

> $(document).ready(function() {
>       var num_elements_to_show = 5;

```
function showFirstTen(num) {
console.log(num);
$("ul.nav > li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu  li:nth-child(n+" + (num + 1) + ")").hide();
}
showFirstTen (num_elements_to_show);
});
```

Here, **num_elements_to_show** is a variable which takes in number that will display that many **li's**

Hope it helps!!